# Create small digit on the image button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I want to know how these numbers on the image button created.

when other item selected , the number increase.

like this

http://www.uploadup.com/di-K7GY.png

Comment: you may be unaware but the link for the image has expired.  Obviously you have already received an answer, but could you please re-add the image to the post.  This will make it useful to future readers of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be easily created by a FrameLayout hosting an ImageView that fills the FrameLayout; a smaller RelativeLayout (or FrameLayout) that has a small red circle background, and inside it a centered TextView.